# create static html pages dynamically cos of SEO

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, web-crawler, googlebot

I am trying how to create static html pages dynamically. 
It is because I am reading that dynamic content is not google friendly, google cannot crawle the content which is coming from database once the page is opened.

in exact example:

```
{{ content_from_db }}
```

this variable is replaced with long text. This long text contains many important keywords of the page. I read that this content is unfortunately not seen by google since it is dynamic.

Then I said, well lets create static html pages dynamically, but i am stuck here not knowing how..

is it possible?

Comment: How are you defining "static" and "dynamic" in this context, and where did you read that "dynamic content is not google friendly"?

Comment: I think he means Google can not index pages generated dynamically.

Comment: are you defining static page as simple html page that should be created n the fly @doniyor

Comment: @AlokAgarwal, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise is completely and utterly false. It is absolutely not the case that Google can't index dynamically created websites. Of course it can: StackOverflow, which has awesome SEO, is just one of the millions of dynamic websites indexed by Google.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible i will give u short example you can proceed with it. we had a similar requirement so what we did was

```
def GenerateDynamicSelectPopulate(model, modelFields):
models=Product
modelsField=productname
str="""$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/%s/?format=json',
    cache: false,
    accepts: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        var options = ''
        for(i = 0; i < data.objects.length; ++i) {
            var str =  '<option value="' + data.objects[i].id + '">'+ %s + '</option>'
            options=options+str
            }
        $('#%s').html(options)
        },
    dataType: "json"
    });"""
```

here replace all '%s' in above code from the value you want similarly for html page u make a string having html code and things that can change make them as %s and provide value at runtime thus you can make html page at runtime

good luck